# How to make this effect in Skrillex' song

Tags: effects

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpwVCVVLfcI
Minute: 0:45

How to make this, sort of, stuttering effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

manual chopping, gating, glitch plugins or combination of all of these.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell if the stutter is repeating the first part very quickly or just gateing it rhythmically.  I'm guessing it's the second option.  Check out Audio Damages "Replicant" plug-in or Camel Audio "Camel Space".  Both killer and useful.  You can probably get somewhere close.

Answer (score 0):

or ... IzoTope Stutter Edit or SugarBytes Artillery. Pretty much any 'beat slicer' type plug-in should be able to get something like that. If you only need to apply the effect in a limited manner you could even manually edit something like that up by copying and repeatedly inserting/replacing the required audio fragment at rhythmic subdivisions of the timebase (ie 16th -> 32nd)

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend to download and play with such VST-plugins as:

[Buffer Override](http://destroyfx.smartelectronix.com/)

[Glitch 1.3](http://illformed.org/plugins/)

Both are absolutely free (or try Glitch 2 which is new and 50 euros, but I hadn't any problems with the old free version since the beginning of 2000's)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely gated. You can also use a tremolo to get this result, at least on my tremolo (Melda Productions) where the depth of the tremolo can go up to 100% and you could also control the rate of the stutter and even the wave shape of it (sine, square, triangle and everything in between and more).

Answer (score 0):

Stelios knows whats up.... this has been a really popular effect in glitch-hop and dubstep lately... I know of three ways that some of these big producers are using to achieve this effect... The most common is Stutter Edit, play around with the loop/gating effects over a synth bass and you should figure it out. Another common way (usually in ableton), which is a bit more difficult, is with a gate sidechained to a muted drum rack. The last one is a  crazy way you can play around with the clip envelopes if it's an audio clip- I know this group 2nutz does this, and I can't remember exactly how it works... I will have my friend show me how he did it again and I'll post it if anybody is interested :D

Answer (score 0):

One thing most people forgot, so I want to mention this->

The Dubstep Bass-sound consist of 2 Elements, Subbass (Sinewave) and Midrange-Bass (The "AIII")

To get the Stutter i would use a Gate as the others Mentioned. As a Modualtor for the Key-In (Sidechain) you should use a very loud and VERY short signal. For example use the first 2-3 MS of a Kickdrum etc. Then get thy rythm right with the modulator. One thing that realy soudns good is if you use groovetempaltes on the modulator. Then the stutter is kinda more "organic"

The sound source of the midraneg bass is a fm-dubstep bass. it is directly from skrillex original song. Just get an fm 8 out.

Modulate One Triangle wave carrier with a sine Modulatior. Control the volume of the modulator with an envelope. now modulate the modulator with a 2nd formant waveform with a pitch of 16.000. Adjust the Volume of the 2nd modulator between 8 and 12.

Play g or f and you get the basic growl. now use a ton of filters, distorion, chorus, reverb and compression to finish the sound.

The Subbass should not be stutter, since that would take away a lot of the energy of the sound.